# How to use Vue Composition API as Global State Across Components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

So I tried to use Vue Composition API as global state. As example, I created file called `useLoading.js` as loading flag.

`useLoading.js`

```
import { reactive, toRefs } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default () => {
  const state = reactive({
    isLoading: false
  })

  const setIsLoading = (loading) => {
    state.isLoading = loading
  }

  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
    setIsLoading
  }
}
```

Then I created component A in which it will call the `setIsLoading` when the button is clicked

`ComponentA.vue`

```
<template>
  <div @click="showLoading" />
</template>

<script>
import useLoading from '@/composable/useLoading'

export default {
  setup () {
    const { setIsLoading } = useLoading()

    function showLoading () {
      setIsLoading(true)
    }

    return {
      showLoading
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I also have component B in which it will use to render a `<div>` when the value of `isLoading` is `true`

`ComponentB.vue`

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isLoading" />
</template>

<script>
import useLoading from '@/composable/useLoading'

export default {
  setup () {
    const { isLoading } = useLoading()

    return {
      isLoading: isLoading
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Yet the value of `isLoading` in `ComponentB.vue` was not change (not reactive). But the value did change when I called in in `ComponentA.vue`

I feel like there is something wrong with my implementation in using Composition API as global state. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Just found out I have to exclude the state from the export function, If I include it inside the export function, it will create other states if it is called in a different place. So the state will not sync between components.

```
import { reactive, toRefs } from '@vue/composition-api'

const state = reactive({
    isLoading: false
})

export default () => {

  const setIsLoading = (loading) => {
    state.isLoading = loading
  }

  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
    setIsLoading
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the way.